# What is the difference between Paypal Payments Standard and Paypal Express Checkout?

Tags: paypal, checkout, standards

I need to implement PayPal on my web page, and I don't know which one to use, Paypal Payments Standard or Paypal Express Checkout or both. To me they seems pretty much the same.

Comment: This belongs on the webmasters site, not stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Website Payments Standard is an outdated, by default insecure, HTML-based solution. Express Checkout is an API-based solution that's more flexible, and would be what I'd go with if I had to start a new integration with PayPal.

Answer (score 1):

I think  Paypal Express Checkout gives the user ability to store their CC info so when they visit your website again(or any other website that uses Paypal Express) the user do not have to enter the CC info again.